# Can I cast Killing Glare with X=0 while no creatures with zero power are on the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I wonder if I am able to cast [Killing Glare](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Killing%20Glare) if there are no powerless creatures on the board?

For example to Extort after casting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you have to pick a legal target (a creature with power 0 or less) when you cast the spell, as instructed by the third step of casting a spell.

> 601.2c The player announces his or her choice of an appropriate player, object, or zone for each target the spell requires. [...]

If you can't, any steps of casting the spell already taken are undone.

> 601.2. [...] If, at any point during the casting of a spell, a player is unable to comply with any of the steps listed below, the casting of the spell is illegal; the game returns to the moment before that spell started to be cast [...]

Comment: Presumably the card would work the way the OP wants if it was worded something more like "If target creature has power X or less, destroy it."

Comment: @thesunneversets, yeah, then any creature would be a valid target. "Destroy a creature with with power X or less." would also allow it to be cast since the creature would be chosen on resolution.